# Neo4j match nodes related to all nodes in collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph of tags, which are related with each other. My goal is to create a Cypher query, which will return all tags that are related to an array of input tags via 1 or 2 hops.

I made a query, which doesn't work quite as intended.

```
MATCH (t:Tag)
WHERE t.name IN ["A", "B", "C"]
WITH t
MATCH (a:Tag)-[:RELATED*1..2]-(t)
RETURN DISTINCT a;
```

This query first finds the nodes `A`, `B`, `C` and then searches for tags, that are related to `A`, `B` **or** `C` via 1 node or less.

What I want to do though is to find tags, which are related to ALL three nodes (`A`, `B` **and** `C`).

---

I know I could concatenate `MATCH` and `WITH` statements, and do something like this:

```
MATCH (t:Tag)-[:RELATED*1..2]-(a:Tag)
WHERE t.name="A"

WITH DISTINCT a
MATCH (t:Tag)-[:RELATED*1..2]-(a)
WHERE t.name="B"

WITH DISTINCT a
MATCH (t:Tag)-[:RELATED*1..2]-(a)
WHERE t.name="C"
...
RETURN DISTINCT a;
```

But it runs painfully slow, when the number of input tags increase (in this case only 3 input tags: `A`, `B`, `C`).

---

So is there a way to make it in one query, similar to my first try?

Comment: Is it important to use a collection of tag names as input, as opposed to several individual tag names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution that only requires a single `MATCH` clause.

```
MATCH (t:Tag)-[:RELATED*..2]-(other:Tag)
WHERE t.name IN ["A", "B", "C"]
WITH t, COLLECT(DISTINCT other) AS others
WITH COLLECT(others) AS coll
RETURN FILTER(x IN coll[0] WHERE ALL(y IN coll[1..] WHERE x IN y)) AS res;
```

- The query finds all the tags (`other`) that are "related" (by up to 2 steps) to each of your named tags (`t`).
- It then uses aggregation to collect the *distinct* `other` nodes for each `t`. In this example, we end up with 3 `others` collections -- 1 for each `t`.
- It then collects all the `others` collections into a single `coll` collection.
- Finally, since the result set is supposed to be the intersection of every `others` collection, the query walks through the nodes in first `others` collection, and extracts the ones that are also in the remaining `others` collections. And, since each `others` collection already contains distinct nodes, the result must also have distinct nodes.

In addition, if you have a lot of tags, the above query can be made a bit faster by:

1. [Creating an index](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.5/query-schema-index.html#schema-index-create-index-on-a-label) (or [uniqueness constraint](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.5/query-constraints.html#constraints-create-uniqueness-constraint), which automatically creates an index for you) on `:Tag(name)`, and then
2. Specifying the use of that index in your query -- by inserting the following clause between the `MATCH` and `WHERE` clauses. Currently, the Cypher engine does not automatically use the index for this specific query.

   ```
   USING INDEX t:Tag(name)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the step-by-step explanation, it sounds reasonable and looks like it should work like I need it to. But (here it comes) when I run the query, it returns a collection of `true` and `false` values. Any idea how to actually get the nodes?

Comment: Oops. I have corrected the query. I should have used `FILTER` instead of `EXTRACT`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
MATCH (t:Tag)-[:RELATED*1..2]-(other:Tag)
WHERE t.name IN ["A", "B", "C"] 
WITH t, collect(other.name) as others
WHERE ALL(x in ["A","B","C"] WHERE x in others)
RETURN t
```

The trick is put all the related nodes for `t` into a collection (others) and use the `ALL` predicate to make sure all of your A,B and C are part of that.

Comment: The syntax of you query is not correct - look at the `WHERE ALL` statement, it doesn't really make sense. Still thanks for the try, I'll look into the `ALL` predicate, maybe it will solve my problem.

Comment: I've just updated my answer with the correct statement.

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood the question. I'm not trying to make sure that `A`, `B` and `C` are in the collection (others), but rather I'm trying to find all other nodes, that are connected to `A`, `B` and `C` simultaneously. So for example if node `D` would have a relationship to all three input nodes, then it would be in the output. Also if node `E` would only be connected to `A` an `B`, but NOT `C`, then it wouldn't be in the output.

Comment: The second query in my question actually works and does what I want, so it should explain what I need. But it is needlessly complicated and I think an easier solution exists. That's all :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative:

```
MATCH shortestPath((t:Tag)<-[:RELATED*1..2]-(source:Tag)) //make sure there are no duplicate paths 
WHERE source.name IN ["A","B","C"] AND NOT source.name = t.name //shortest path for identical node would throw an exception
WITH COLLECT(t) as tags //all tags that were reachable, with duplicates for reachable from multiple tags
UNWIND tags as tag //for each tag
WITH tag, tags //using with as match would be a drastic slowdown
WHERE size(filter(t IN tags WHERE ID(t) = ID(tag))) = 3 //if it is connected to all three, it must have been matched three times
RETURN DISTINCT m //since any match will still be in there 3 (or n) times
```

It first matches all reachable tags. All tags that were reachable from all tags in a list with the length n must have been matched n times if shortestPath is used. If you then filter by that criteria (present n times) the wanted tags can be retrieved with distinct.