# Neo4j: Filter by time range + group by + return relevant paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a database with nodes Persons, Cars and Accidents. I'd like to display the accidents
of the last 3 cars involved in accidents (it must be at least the 2nd accident of the car).

I quite managed to do that but it's not exactly working as intended, cf questions in the code.

Here is the code to reproduce the example:

```
CREATE
  (p1:Person {name: 'Paul'})-[:DRIVES]->(c1:Car {name: 'Car A'}),
  (p2:Person {name: 'John'})-[:DRIVES]->(c2:Car {name: 'Car B'}),
  (p3:Person {name: 'Mike'})-[:DRIVES]->(c3:Car {name: 'Car C'}),
  (p4:Person {name: 'Mark'})-[:DRIVES]->(c4:Car {name: 'Car D'}),
  (p5:Person {name: 'Eric'})-[:DRIVES]->(c5:Car {name: 'Car E'}),
  (p6:Person {name: 'Ross'})-[:DRIVES]->(c6:Car {name: 'Car F'}),
  (p7:Person {name: 'Kobe'})-[:DRIVES]->(c7:Car {name: 'Car G'}),
  (c1)-[:IS_DOER]->(a1: Accident {acc_time: time('23:15'), acc_date: date('2020-05-01')})<-[:IS_VICTIM]-(c2),
  (c1)-[:IS_DOER]->(a2: Accident {acc_time: time('02:25'), acc_date: date('2020-03-18')})<-[:IS_VICTIM]-(c3),
  (c1)-[:IS_DOER]->(a3: Accident {acc_time: time('13:40'), acc_date: date('2020-04-12')})<-[:IS_VICTIM]-(c4),
  (c1)-[:IS_DOER]->(a4: Accident {acc_time: time('04:00'), acc_date: date('2020-04-21')})<-[:IS_VICTIM]-(c5),
  (c2)-[:IS_DOER]->(a6: Accident {acc_time: time('04:40'), acc_date: date('2020-04-12')})<-[:IS_VICTIM]-(c3),
  (c2)-[:IS_DOER]->(a7: Accident {acc_time: time('01:50'), acc_date: date('2020-05-03')})<-[:IS_VICTIM]-(c4),
  (c3)-[:IS_DOER]->(a8: Accident {acc_time: time('01:20'), acc_date: date('2020-04-29')})<-[:IS_VICTIM]-(c5),
  (c6)-[:IS_DOER]->(a9: Accident {acc_time: time('01:20'), acc_date: date('2020-05-04')})<-[:IS_VICTIM]-(c7),
  (c4)-[:IS_DOER]->(a10: Accident {acc_time: time('03:10'), acc_date: date('2020-05-05')})<-[:IS_VICTIM]-(c7)
;
```

And my query:

```
// What is the query about:
// condition 1: Count number of accidents that happened during night (range time 23:00-05:00) per car
// condition 2: Keep cars with at least 2 night accidents
// condition 3: Among these, return only 3 last cars involved in the accidents, with all 
//              their accident paths (Person - Car - Accident) 
WITH [time('23:00'), time('05:00')] as time_range
UNWIND time_range AS time_val 
MATCH path = (c:Car)-[]-(a:Accident)
WHERE CASE WHEN time_range[0] <= time_range[1] THEN time_range[0] <= a.acc_time <= time_range[0]
           ELSE a.acc_time >= time_range[0] OR a.acc_time <= time_range[1] END // condition 1 OK
WITH c, count(distinct a) as cnt_accidents, MAX(a.acc_date) as latest_acc_date_for_car, 
     collect(a) as coll_accidents // how can I use collect in the next match pattern?
ORDER BY cnt_accidents desc
LIMIT 3 // condition 3 OK
WHERE cnt_accidents >= 2 // condition 2 OK. Why the WHERE clause cannot be set before ORDER BY ? Is it optimal?
MATCH path = (p:Person)-[]-(c:Car)-[]-(a:Accident)
WHERE a.acc_time >= time('23:00') OR a.acc_time <= time('05:00') // set condition 1 hardcoded
// because cannot access time_range at this step. Shouldn't it be better to use results 
// from collect to display relevant accidents?
RETURN path ;
```

As I would like to store this query in a procedure, I'd like to keep the time_range parameter.

I already saw on SO that it could be possible to use collect in a way similar to what I want, but couldn't manage : [Neo4j match nodes related to all nodes in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018818/neo4j-match-nodes-related-to-all-nodes-in-collection)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out how to solve it:

```
WITH [time('23:00'), time('05:00')] as time_range
UNWIND time_range AS time_val 
MATCH path = (c:Car)-[]-(a:Accident)
WHERE CASE WHEN time_range[0] <= time_range[1] THEN time_range[0] <= a.acc_time <= time_range[0]
           ELSE a.acc_time >= time_range[0] OR a.acc_time <= time_range[1] END // condition 1 OK
WITH c, count(distinct a) as cnt_accidents, MAX(a.acc_date) as latest_acc_date_for_car, 
     collect(a) as coll_accidents
ORDER BY CASE WHEN cnt_accidents >= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END desc, latest_acc_date_for_car desc
LIMIT 3 // condition 3 OK
WHERE cnt_accidents >= 2 // condition 2 OK
UNWIND coll_accidents AS acc // Getting only accidents nodes from the previous collect
MATCH path = (c:Car)-[]-(acc) // Matching only accidents nodes from the previous collect
RETURN path ;
```

To answer my questions:

- How can I use collect in the next match pattern? By using UNWIND
  later on and use it back in MATCH

> ```
> UNWIND coll_accidents AS acc // Getting only accidents nodes from the
> previous collect MATCH path = (c:Car)-[]-(acc)
> ```

- Why the WHERE clause cannot be set before ORDER BY ? I still don't understand why, but I found a work around by making sure that group by is ordered by condition first. Otherwise in original query, it was ordered by cnt_accidents, not by cnt_accidents>=2. Which made the query wrong.

> ```
> ORDER BY CASE WHEN cnt_accidents >= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END desc, latest_acc_date_for_car desc
> ```